# ArgumentError with ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I have a login that after saving the new user is supposed to send an email. This works fine locally but on the production server I keep getting this error in my log files:

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (8 for 6)):
  app/models/user_observer.rb:3:in `after_save'
  /usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/observer.rb:185:in `notify_observers'
  /usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/observer.rb:184:in `each'
  /usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/observer.rb:184:in `notify_observers'
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:13:in `create'
```

My user_observer:

```
class UserObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer 
  def after_save(user)  
   UserMailer.deliver_welcome_email(user)  
  end 
end
```

My user_mailer:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def welcome_email(user)  
    recipients user.email 
    from "MilitaryMoveIt <militarymoveit@gmail.com>"  
    subject "Welcome to My Awesome Site"  
    sent_on Time.now 
    body :user => user
  end 
end
```

My user_controller:

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    @user_session = UserSession.new
    @user.level = 'Trial'
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = "Account registered!"
      redirect_to account_url
    else
      render :layout => 'user_sessions_new', :template => 'user_sessions/new'
    end
  end
```

I would really appreciate anyone that can shine some light on what I am missing here.

Edit: This is what is being passed:

```
Processing UsersController#create (for 184.40.5.17 at 2010-08-06 12:38:23) [POST]
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"name"=>"lauren", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "login"=>"looloobs", 
 "email"=>"laurenrothlisberger@gmail.com"}, "x"=>"82", "y"=>"14", "action"=>"create", 
 "authenticity_token"=>"qvQLB9w/pJOWOFzKy6HadbxRieejhQ8Hmry36EAIIwc=", "controller"=>"users"}
Sent mail to laurenrothlisberger@gmail.com
```

I have no idea what the X and Y parameters are.. is this the problem, trying to pass these?

Answer (score 0):

If it's working on locally but not on your production server, do you have the same environment for both? Same Ruby and Rails versions?

What's different about these two environments?

Comment: both environments are running the same versions of ruby and rails. thanks